# Can I use ASP.NET AJAX History without having .NET 3.5 SP1 installed?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, browser-history

Is it possible to use this feature on a server that only have .NET 2.0 installed? After an initial look into how AJAX history is implemented, I'm not sure it would be easy. I am just curious if anyone knows of a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old "futures" include that feature:  http://quickstarts.asp.net/futures/

That's what you'll need to use.